# No encuentro como solucionar el error 60 en wordspress

Tags: wordpress

estoy realizando una pagina web en wordspress pero al intentar utilizar las herramientas para editar encabezados etc, me aparece el siguiente error

```
Error: Minified React error #60; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=60 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at F (https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg-core/v16.8.1/build/vendors/react-dom.min.js?m=1697141320i&ver=18:1:8950)
    at Rr (https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg-core/v16.8.1/build/vendors/react-dom.min.js?m=1697141320i&ver=18:1:68236)
    at xl (https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg-core/v16.8.1/build/vendors/react-
```

No domino con totalidad el tema de la programación así que no encuentro la manera de solucionarlo.
No puedo subir el error completo porque no  tengo suficiente reputación en el foro

fui a la url mencionada  https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=60 pero no comprendo muy bien el paso a seguir

Comment: En esa URL te aparece el error abajo en rojo. Copias ese texto y lo buscas en google, donde vas a encontrar varias respuestas ahí tienes que ver cual aplica a tu caso

Comment: pues empieza con lo basico, testing, primero intenta averiguar si es un complemento que lo causa, ve probando uno a uno, desactivandolo, si aun nada prueba a cambiar de tema, recuerda tener todo siempre actualizado y si usas complementos que sean compatibles con tu versión de wordpress, también te invito a leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas